# Secure simple JAX-WS web service in Java, following OWASP recommendations

Tags: java, xml, security, soap, jax-ws

In Java 1.6+ it's simple to provide a JAX-WS 2.0 SOAP web service, even without external libraries:

It's more or less: We annotate service interface and class with `@WebService`, add `@WebParam` to the arguments of the methods provided, invoke `Endpoint.publish` and *there we go*! I don't even have to annotate the input or output data classes for JAXB.

But how safe is it to provide a web service like that?

I'm not referring to the business view (is the user allowed to access a certain record, how to implement role based access control etc.) but the infrastructure side, especially concerning XML handling.

For example, [OWASP recommends](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Web_Service_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Schema_Validation):

> Web services must validate SOAP payloads against their associated XML schema definition (XSD).

Will I have to do that manually? Will the default JAX-WS 2.0 implementation included in the JDK do that for me? Do I have to enable that using configuration, annotations etc.?

Moreover, OWASP recommends:

> - Validation against malformed XML entities
> - Validation against XML Bomb attacks
> - Validating against external entity attacks

If I provide a service as simply as explained at the beginning, will I have to take additional measures to protect against external entity attacks? Or against XML deserialisation attacks ("ysoserial" and similar stuff)? XML bombs / DoS?

Do you know an extension to the [OWASP Web Service Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Web_Service_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Schema_Validation) than explains how to implement the recommendations in a simple web service provided using the Java 1.6+ standard feature scope?

For the security considerations, let's assume the most recent patch version of Java 8 is used. My references to Java 1.6 are meant to refer to the [SOAP web service "out-of-the-box" capabilities introduced in that version](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/jax-ws-2-141894.html) (RI included without need for custom provided JARs).

Answer (score 0):

Considering the example of WS deployment that you've mentioned: it seems to me, that behind the scenes this method will use both Java embedded HttpServer (to manage the HTTP requests and HTTP responses to/from your web service) and internal JAX-WS Reference Implementation, also known as Metro.

[Metro's page on GitHub](https://javaee.github.io/metro-jax-ws/)

I'm not absolutely sure about which implementation of JAX-WS RI is used in 1.6, most likely it is the same Metro.
So it would be a good point to walk through the Metro documentation to get the needed information considering its security specs.
As from my point of view, this solution is good for some testing reasons, when you need to check your web service as fast as it possible. But it is only my opinion.
Generally this approach is also has a right to be used in projects.

Also I have no any information whether OWASP recommendations are included into related JAX-WS specifications. If they are then Metro probably implements it out of the box.